# Google+ APIs have been shut down as of March 7, what needs to update?

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, google-api-client, google-client

Google+ APIs have been shut down as of March 7, as they described below

https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown

Here is my code snippet which I used in application but the application is still working with google login.
Also, I got no email regarding this issue.

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
                    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Sign-In is providing with some of the user-related data. I do not know what all data Google+ APIs exposed but you can look into what Google Sign-In or Google Authentication provides.

[Try Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start).

[Start Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating).

[Plus API Deprecation Notes](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/api-deprecation).

Google Plus discontinuation was informed via email to users and developers. It was also covered in many tech news blogs and sites.